# Laravel route not defined but it is defined

Tags: php, laravel

Route [partner.file.download] not defined. is the error i get, but this route is defined. and yes i am logged in as a 'partner'

Web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:partner', 'prefix' => 'partner', 'as' => 'partner.'], function(){

    Route::resource('/dashboard', App\Http\Controllers\partner\PartnerController::class);
   Route::resource('/profile', App\Http\Controllers\partner\ProfileController::class);
   Route::resource('/file', App\Http\Controllers\partner\FileController::class);
});
```

controller

```
  public function show($id)
    {
        $file = File::findOrFail($id);

        return view('partner.file.viewfile', compact('file'));
    }
    
    public function download($id)
    {
        return view('partner.file.index', compact('file));
    }
```

index.blade

```
  <tbody>
                    @foreach($files as $file)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$file->title}} </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-big btn-succes" style="background: orange;" href="{{ route('partner.file.show', $file->id) }}">View</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-big btn-succes" style="background: green;" href="{{ route('partner.file.download', $file->id) }}"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{@$file->language->name}} </td>
                        @foreach($file->tag as $tags)
                        <td style="background:{{$tags['color']}} ;">{{@$tags->name}} </td>
                        @endforeach
                        
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Resource routes [automatically have 7 default routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller), but any others, such as your download route, need to be manually created.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but it's not defined.

Comment: Don't you need to add a ```name()``` method to your routes first?

Comment: @Innovin They have `as` on their group, and resource routes are generated with their names.

Comment: @aynber Oh. I don't usually make use of the resource route. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PLEASE READ THE [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes)**

as @aynber mentioned in the comments, when you create routes using `resource()`, it will create `index, create, store, show, edit, update and delete`. There is no "download" route here.

If you need a route that is not in the list of default routes (here you need download), you should create that one explicitly as below:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:partner', 'prefix' => 'partner', 'as' => 'partner.'], function(){

   Route::resource('/dashboard', App\Http\Controllers\partner\PartnerController::class);
   Route::resource('/profile', App\Http\Controllers\partner\ProfileController::class);
   Route::resource('/file', App\Http\Controllers\partner\FileController::class);
});


// HERE: you add the named route you need
Route::get(
    '/file/download',
    [App\Http\Controllers\partner\FileController::class, 'download']
)->name('file.download');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Route::resource() the only accessible methods to the controller are index, create, store, show, edit, update and delete.

[You can check this at the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Please share more details. Is there any chance to resolve the problem?